# Adding fractions of unlike denominators

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

Given $\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{r} = ?$ , can I simplify the equation by multiplying the equation with $rs$?

and the equation is simplified as $rs * (\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{r}) = r + s$

Is this a valid operation?

Comment: It is tue that $rs\left(\frac1r+\frac1s\right)=r+s$ for all $r\ne 0$ and $s\ne 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just $$\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{r+s}{rs}.$$
If $$\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{r}=t$$ so
$$r+s=trs$$

But $$r+s\neq\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{r},$$ of course.